# gfortran failing to link program on M1 Mac, architecture arm64

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm writing an example script in Fortran 2008 and compiling it with gfortran on my M1 mac. When trying to compile it, I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "___mymodule_MOD_myfunc", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in cca7mVdW.o
  "___mymodule_MOD_mysub", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in cca7mVdW.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My gfortran version:

```
GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 12.1.0) 12.1.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

The error only occurs when I use a function or subroutine from a different file.

example.f08

```
program myProgram
    use myModule
    implicit none
    
    integer :: myInteger = 10
    real :: myFloat = 5.2
    complex :: myTuple = (1.0, -0.5)
    character :: myChar = "E"
    character(len=5) :: myString = "Hello"
    logical :: myBool = .true.

    print *, myInteger
    print *, myFloat
    print *, myTuple
    print *, myChar
    print *, myString
    print *, myBool

    print *
    print *, myInteger
    ! From the module "myModule"
    myInteger = myFunc(myInteger)
    print *, myInteger
    ! Also from the module "myModule"
    call mySub(myInteger)

end program myProgram
```

module.f08:

```
module myModule

    implicit none

    private
    public myFunc, mySub
    
contains

    integer function myFunc(input) result(output)
        integer, intent(in) :: input

        output = input + 1

    end function myFunc

    subroutine mySub(input)
        integer, intent(in) :: input

        print *, input - 1

    end subroutine mySub


end module myModule
```

Comment: Please specify the exact commands used to compile program.

Comment: Note also these are not compile time errors, but linker errors

Comment: It is possible that the precise aspect of the linking related to the architecture is not covered in the linked question and its answers, but that's the canonical question. If you add detail to this question which shows it isn't answered there, we can correct that.

Comment: Either way, please do add the detail requested by albert and anything else relevant.

Comment: The command I used to get the error in question was ```gfortran example.f08```